Не запускается Android-игра после редактирования текстовых данных
Я новичок в программировании, и я решил впервые взяться за перевод Android игры. Проблема заключается в том, что в файле 367138 символов. После перевода количество символов возросло. Скомпилировав файлы в .apk я попробовал запустить игру, но дальше экрана загрузки ничего не было. Однако, когда символов в файле ровно столько, сколько и было - игра прекрасно запускается и отображает русский текст. Игра написана на движке Unity. Жанр игры: Визуальная новелла. Проекта самой игры у меня нет. Кто знает из за чего это и как решить эту проблему?

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! Добавьте ваши попытки с приложенным кодом. Справка поможет оформить ваш вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

В былые времена так игры и локализовывали, где-то подрезая текст, чтобы где-то вместилось побольше.
